# Cинонимизировать на мете метки "раньше-было-лучше" и "нытьё"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, мета

На днях на мете [появилась](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5) новая метка - [раньше-было-лучше](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5).

Мне кажется, [у нас уже есть](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%91) метка для этого - [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91).

Надо бы синонимизировать.

Comment: [tag:нытьё] - это крик отчаяния, а [tag:раньше-было-лучше] - это нотка грусти и меланхолии (｡•́︿•̀｡)

Comment: @Suvitruf для крика было бы [meta-tag:рыдание], а не [meta-tag:нытьё]. З.Ы. Синоним можно предложить на [странице синонимов метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%91/synonyms).

Comment: Заодно и [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315785/339911) обнаружился. Ну, это не удивительно :)

Comment: @alexolut haha_classic.jpg

Answer (score -6):

[раньше-было-лучше](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5) надо просто удалить, т.к. никакой пользы данная метка не несет.

Формальные признаки ненужности метки:

- метка не может использоваться самостоятельно (быть единственной на вопросе)
- не существует специалистов по теме метки ([раньше-было-лучше](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5))
- к метке проблематично написать описание и инструкцию по применению